# onCreateWindowで作ったWebViewでloadUrlを呼ぶとshouldOverrideUrlLoadingが呼ばれません

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

onCreateWindow で作った WebView で loadUrl を使って次の URL に遷移すると shouldOverrideUrlLoading が呼ばれず、onPageStarted がいきなり呼ばれます。

親ウインドウ (つまり、onCreateWindow を呼んだ方)では、

- shouldOverrideUrlLoading
- onPageStarted

の順番で呼ばれますが、
子ウインドウは、onPageStarted がいきなり呼ばれてしまいます。
そのため、loadURL で次の URL へ遷移したり、location.href にカスタム URL スキームが入ったものを実行する JavaScript を loadURL で実行すると、shouldOverrideUrlLoading が呼ばれないので、
カスタム URL スキームの処理ができず、
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
のエラーが発生します。
onPageStarted で、カスタム URL スキームの処理ができればいいのですが、
できないので困っています。

どなたか同じようなケースで解決された方がいらっしゃいましたら、
解決方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。